# Test for differences between groups when each subject was measured several times

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I have data in which values of independent objects were measured, and there were several measurements (usually 5 or 6) per object from random points separated in space. An example of data is provided below.

In the plot of the data, it is visible that the points of the same object are more similar to each other than the points of different objects. Thus it seems that to assume that each point is independent is not valid.

[image]

**Questions:**

1. In this situation, what is an appropriate approach to testing if groups A and B differ statistically significantly? I think that ordinary Mann-Whitney/Kruskal-Wallis or similar test is not appropriate, as there are several measurements of the same object.
2. How could this approach be implemented in **R**?

Example of data in **R**:

```r
my_data <- 
    structure(list(object = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
.Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),
class = "factor"),
group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(63.3, 63.6, 70.8, 60.9, 66.6, 
10.9, 9.3, 14.6, 9.9, 20.2, 18.1, 27.9, 36.8, 38.2, 37.3, 34.5, 
30.6, 7.5, 11.4, 9.2, 7.7, 9, 77.8, 69.2, 65.6, 72.7, 76.9, 84.2, 
70.7, 73.4, 72.7, 71.3, 70.9, 57.2, 63.2, 56, 13.5, 21.3, 12, 
13.6, 27.6, 22.2, 17.1, 6.8, 9.5, 9.5, 9, 16.2, 9.5, 10.7, 10.6, 
10.8, 9.6, 7.1, 8.2, 86.6, 81.5, 100.3, 86.7, 89.3, 77)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -61L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had many more levels of the object variable, this might be a simpler problem. A standard approach would be to fit the linear model using generalized least squares (GLS), given the lack of balance. By lack of balance, I mean each object was measured a different number of times.

Using GLS, you can estimate a group difference based on the response variable, but adjust this group difference for the correlations between observations obtained from the same object. We can also assume that the observations had different variances depending on the group to which they belonged. Your plot appears to suggest that objects in group A had more variance than objects in group B.

Given your data, here's how we would proceed:

```
library(nlme)
summary(mod <- gls(
  value ~ group, my_data, corCompSymm(form = ~ 1 | object),
  varIdent(form = ~ 1 | group)))

Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: value ~ group 
  Data: my_data 
      AIC      BIC   logLik
  398.514 408.9016 -194.257

Correlation Structure: Compound symmetry
 Formula: ~1 | object 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Rho 
0.9701706 
Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | group 
 Parameter estimates:
        A         B 
1.0000000 0.5969376 

Coefficients:
                Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  60.83432  16.15268  3.766206  0.0004
groupB      -38.29712  17.97176 -2.130961  0.0373

[Skipped lines]

Residual standard error: 32.72284 
Degrees of freedom: 61 total; 59 residual
```

We can break down the results in how they are printed.

The first thing we pay attention to is the Correlation Structure. We assumed it to be compound symmetry by using the syntax, `corCompSym(form = ~ 1 | object)`. This means we believe that the observations within an object are correlated at the same value. Based on the results, the software believes this value to be .97. This means the correlation between response values within each object are very highly correlated, almost identical as the repeated measures of each object do not show much variability, relative to the variability across objects.

We move on to the next set of results under the Variance function. This suggests that observations in group A have a residual standard deviation of $1 \times 32.72$, 32.72 is the residual standard deviation printed at the bottom of the results. The observations in group B have a residual standard deviation of $.597 \times 32.72$, much smaller as your plot suggests. We have these different variances because we specified the `weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | group)` option.

We next proceed to the coefficients which appear to be of topmost interest to you. The group difference adjusted for the correlation is 38.3 points, with a p-value of .037. The *p*-value would be much smaller had we ignored the correlation between the observations (I found it be near 0).

Having walked through these steps, there are reasons to be skeptical of these results. Most importantly, there is good reason to doubt the .97 correlation we estimated given the small sample size we have (10 objects). And if that estimate is wrong, our group difference alongside statistical test may be adversely affected.

You could actually simplify the analysis by averaging the response within each object to obtain a single value per object. This is a conservative approach as you lose sample size. Though given that high .97 correlation or more importantly, your plot above, the repeated measures about each object do not contain much additional information about the object.

One can proceed thus:

```
new_dat <- aggregate(value ~ object + group, my_data, mean)
head(new_dat); nrow(new_dat)

  object group    value
1      1     A 65.04000
2      5     A 73.21818
3      7     A 18.18571
4     10     A 86.90000
5      2     B 13.83333
6      3     B 34.21667
[1] 10
```

We now have 10 rows of data, one per object.

First, what is the group mean difference?

```
coef(lm(value ~ group, new_dat))
(Intercept)      groupB 
   60.83597   -38.27042
```

The group mean difference of 38.3 is very close to the value we obtained earlier. Next, we can conduct an independent samples *t*-test using Welch's adjustment to account for heteroskedasticity:

```
t.test(value ~ group, new_dat)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  value by group
t = 2.246, df = 4.84, p-value = 0.07641
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -5.969281 82.510118
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
       60.83597        22.56556
```

We now have a new statistical test. Assuming there is no group difference, we have an 8% chance of observing the mean difference we have observed. That's a pretty low number, however it does not account for all sources of uncertainty, such as having run a number of models to reach this point.

---

**Edit in relation to comments**

GLS does assume normality. To examine the complete set of normality assumptions, we can refit this model as a multilevel or mixed-effects model. When we assume that the observations within objects are correlated at the same value using GLS, it is equivalent to fitting a mixed effects model permitting the intercept of the model to be different depending on the object. This kind of varying intercept is known as a random-intercepts model.

These two approaches are equivalent under normal circumstances, but on trying just now, I just realized that they differ slightly when you permit heteroskedasticity, i.e. by using `weights = varIdent(...)`. I will proceed thus:

```
mod.me <- lme(
  value ~ group, my_data, random = ~ 1 | object,
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | group))
```

The formula reads, predict value using the group variable `(value ~ group)`, but permit the intercept to be different depending on the object `(random = ~ 1 | object)`.

In this model, we can test that the residuals using the syntax, `resid(mod.me)`. However means by which you test the residuals for normality is up to you. The additional check is we assumed the individual object means arise from a normal distribution. We can retrieve them using `ranef(mod.me)[, 1]` and test them however we test normality. Note that at larger sample sizes, especially of the number of objects, central limit theorem kicks in, such that we may trust the inference.

Parameterizing the model this way, as a mixed effects model, shows the need for a larger number of objects in your toy example. It is impossible to verify the normality of 10 data points.

If there are more than two groups, there is the emmeans package. I do not use post-hoc tests in my own work, so I just you read the documentation. Normally, I might read up to give you a better response but I do not value such corrections. The simplest application of pairwise comparisons would be: `pairs(emmeans(mod.me, "group"))`. There is a `contrasts()` function in there too.

Comment: I didn't know about GLS until now, thanks. **About the data:** Yes, there are more objects in the original dataset. Several more **related questions: 1)** Does GLS assumes normality? If yes, how should I check this assumption in this context? **2)** There are more grouping variables (say, `groups_b`, `groups_c`, etc.). And if I want to test which of those groupings lead to statistically significant differences, is it sufficient to apply the procedures you suggest and then correct the p-values for multiple comparisons (`p.adjust()`)? (You can update your answer instead or writing a comment).

Comment: About the normality – now it's clear to me. To know about possible *post-hoc* procedures is also good. But I meant a different thing and, most probably, wrote not clear enough: by saying "different group variables", I meant, e.g., "does `value` differs significantly between *(a)* `age_groups`, *(b)* `price_groups`, *(c)* `color_groups`, etc." After doing those a, b, c, ... tests, is it recommended to do p-value corrections? (Maybe you answered this for me, but it is a lot of information for me to digest)

Comment: I see. I now understand. If you wanted to use statistical significance in the traditional way of confirmatory a priori hypothesis testing, then maybe it might be necessary. With a mixed effects model as above, I wouldn't adjust the p-values. If you just considered your p-values as a measure of noisiness of estimates with smaller p being better, I'd leave them as they are. You can pose this as its own question.

Comment: I placed my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359545/).

Answer (score 1):

As you wish to compare between groups, your main problem is how to account for clustering within each 'object'. Here is a solution using generalized estimating equations (GEE), which adjusts standard errors of the regression coefficients for correlation between outcome values. The solution is very similar to the GLS solution:

```
library(geepack)
testGee <- geeglm(value ~ group, family=gaussian("identity"), data = my_data, id=object, corstr="exchangeable")

# Here the outcome ('value') is assumed to be normally distributed, and means
# depend on 'group' by a linear model: value = intercept (for group = A), and
# value = intercept + groupB (for group B). The correlation is specified as 
# 'exchangeable' which means each pair of observations in an 'object' is 
# assumed to have the same correlation.

summary(testGee)

Call:
geeglm(formula = value ~ group, family = gaussian("identity"), 
    data = my_data, id = object, corstr = "exchangeable")

 Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)    60.83   12.92 22.16 2.51e-06 ***
groupB        -38.38   14.92  6.62   0.0101 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Estimated Scale Parameters:
            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)    455.1   202.3

Correlation: Structure = exchangeable  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha   0.8869  0.1523
Number of clusters:   10   Maximum cluster size: 11 

# An ANOVA gives the same outcome as the t-test for 'groupB' above in
# this case, as there is only one predictor variable / parameter in the
# model (for difference between groups), but ...
anova(testGee)
Analysis of 'Wald statistic' Table
Model: gaussian, link: identity
Response: value
Terms added sequentially (first to last)

      Df   X2 P(>|Chi|)  
group  1 6.62      0.01 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```