# Are p-value corrections needed for separate tests with various grouping variables?

Tags: r, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I have a dataset (find an example below) in which there are many factor variables (`group_a`, `group_b`, `group_c`, etc.; some factor variables fave missing values) and a numeric variable (`value`). I want to test if `value` differs significantly among levels of factor variables (`value` between levels of  `group_a`,  `value` between levels of `group_b`, etc.).  After I did all the tests, should I correct p-values for multiple comparisons? What are the reasons for and what are against doing the corrections?

An example of dataset:

```r
my_data <- read.table(text = "
   object group_a group_b group_c value
1       1       A       G       T  65.0
2       2       B       H       Y  13.8
3       3       B       G       Y  34.2
4       4       B       H       Y   9.0
5       5       A       G       Y  73.2
6       6       B       G       Y  58.8
7       7       A      NA       T  18.2
8       8       B       G       Y  10.1
9       9       B       H       Y   9.5
10     10       A      NA       Y  86.9")
```

(This is a simplified and extended version of the dataset used in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359420/)).